# Extract multipe elements from Json Object in C#

Tags: c#, json

I want to read values of SelectData in loop from following json string

```
[
  {
   "FlightCombination": {},
   "SelectData": "RwoAAB+LCAAAAAAABADNAA"
  },
  {
   "FlightCombination": {},
   "SelectData": "0QoAAB+LCAAAAAAABADA=="
  },
  {
   "FlightCombination": {},
   "SelectData": "WwoAAB+LCAAAAAAABAD" 
  }
]
```

My code so far:

```
string flightselectkey;
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(flightlistingdetail);
foreach (var selectdata in dynObj) {
  flightselectkey = selectdata["SelectData"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following Json object:

```
public class MyJsonObject
{
    public string FlightCombination { get; set; }
    public string SelectData { get; set; }
}
```

The json string can be deserialized to the specified .NET type:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string jsonString = @"[
          {
            ""FlightCombination"": ""{ }"",
            ""SelectData"": ""RwoAAB +LCAAAAAAABADNAA""
          },
          {
            ""FlightCombination"": ""{ }"",
            ""SelectData"": ""0QoAAB+LCAAAAAAABADA==""
          },
          {
            ""FlightCombination"": ""{ }"",
            ""SelectData"": ""WwoAAB +LCAAAAAAABAD""
          }
        ]";


        var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyJsonObject>>(jsonString);

        List<string> dataList = jsonObject.Select(x => x.SelectData).ToList();

        dataList.ForEach(data =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        });

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thats great. How can i save x.SelectData in string?

Comment: I have just updated the code. With `jsonObject.Select(x => x.SelectData).ToList();` you are projecting the 'SelectData' field and storing all of them in a list.